# .animationImages API Cocos 2D?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am looking to do something similar to the API in UIImageView where you supply say 5 images and through a certain duration the UIImageView will switch through those images. I am looking to do this in a CCSprite but the only ways I hear of doing this is customizing frames of the Node or something like that.

Does someone know an easy way to achieve something like this where I provide say 5 images and I want it to cycle though them in 4 seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    //initialize anitmation
    CCAnimation *anime= [[CCAnimation alloc] initWithName:@"anime" delay:4.0];

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            [anime addFrameWithFilename:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"frame%d.png", i]];
    }

    id animeAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anime]];

   [self runAction:animeAction];
```

It takes 5 images and animate them in 4.0 periods.

----- Edit -----
Here is how can you do it with new Cocos2d Api 1.0.1 :

```
    //initialize anitmation
    CCAnimation *anime= [CCAnimation animation];
    anime.delay = 4.0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            [anime addFrameWithFilename:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"frame%d.png", i]];
    }

    id animeAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anime]];

   [self runAction:animeAction];
```

Comment: Wow that is superb! 2 Questions:
1. If I have 5 images does that mean I have 5 lines of ..addFrameWithFileName?
2. Will this animation run indefinitely?

Comment: Actually there is a problem with this code. There is no such API as initWithName, there is only initWithFrames. If you intended initWithFrames how would we mod the code so that it will still achieve the same thing? Also disregard that question about if it will run indefinitely. But what would the answer be to #1 also?

Comment: Here is the cocos2d documentation for CCAnimation class. You can check it and see initWithName : http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.9.0-beta2/interface_c_c_animation.html#afd643251bc26a4ed7dcf3ce1247dc4cd

Comment: About your first comment, q1 yes you'll have 5 lines of addFrameWithFilename and yeap it's also run the animation indefinitely

Comment: @tylerdurden you linked to a totally outdated (January 2010) version of the API reference. Maybe you should update your bookmarks? ;)  Here's the most updated (and complete) API ref: http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/annotated.html

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I realized that too! So since that API is now depreciated how would I modify the above code to conform to the more recent API?

Comment: updated the answer, thank you for noticing, It's been long time, I'm not coding for IOS with cocos2d :) @LearnCocos2D

Comment: Thanks once again. Works perfectly!

Comment: When I try and implement this, I receive an error `NSInvalidArgumentException reason: '-[HelloWorldLayer displayedFrame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'` This is the only code in my app, I just erased the hello world label and pasted this in with my image name in place of frame.png of course. Using Cocos2d v 1.0.1 or v2 had same result. Do you have any suggestions @LearnCocos2d or @tylerdurden?

Answer (score 1):

Create 5 Sprites with the 5 different images. Place them all at the same position. Set 4 of the sprites to be invisible (sprite.visible = NO).

When you want to change the sprites you only need to set another sprite to visible and the currently visible one to invisible. You can also apply actions like CCFadeTo to fade out one sprite while fading in another.

If you use fading, make sure you still set the visible property for performance reasons. Sprites with opacity of 0 are still rendered, while sprites that are not visible aren't.

Comment: Nice answer. How should I set the duration though, how show I go upon doing that?

Comment: [self scheduleSelector:@selector(nextSprite:) interval:4];

Comment: Scheduled selector is one way to do it, you can also use an action CCSequence.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `CCAnimation`, `CCAnimate` and `CCSpriteFrame` classes.

The `CCSpriteFrame` represents a piece of a larger texture known as a sprite sheet. You can put your five images into one sheet.

`CCAnimation` allows you to create an animation out of a sequence of such frames and to set the **speed** at which the animation runs.

And `CCAnimate` allows you to run that animation as an **action**:

```
[node runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animationInstance restoreOriginal:NO]];
```

.

### Links

[CCSpriteFrame class reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/1.0.0/interface_c_c_sprite_frame.html)

[CCAnimation class reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/1.0.0/interface_c_c_animation.html)

[CCAnimate class reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/1.0.0/interface_c_c_animate.html)

[Zwoptex for creating sprite sheets](http://zwoptexapp.com/) - There is a free flash version around too

Comment: I would rather not use a sprite sheet in my case since all the resources in my project are already in there and in this case I would have a lot of reworking to do in order to get the actual sprite sheet in the project! Can I do this with individual images?

Comment: You can. Just create the CCSpriteFrames using CCSprites: `CCSpriteFrame *frameVersionOfSprite = [spriteYouveAlreadyCreated displayedFrame]`

Comment: The code sample that @tylerdurden has provided is very useful for your exact case and our answers compliment each other well, one providing the background, one providing the code example.